# Compress old log files and move to new directory

Tags: zip, archive

I have a folder `/home/usr/logs/` which contain log files which are older than 1 day. I wish to compress all the log files older than one day to separate compressed archives (e.g. zip or tar.gz) and move them to the folder `/home/usr/logs/archive`.

The log files are on naming formats, such as `valid.app5s.log.1019`, `app5s.gf3sts.1019`, `valid.app5s.gf3log.1019`, `app5s.gf3log.1019`, `app5s.gf1sts.1019`, `valid.app5s.gf1log.1019`, `app5s.sts.1019`.

I tried like this:

```
find .  -mtime +1 -exec zip filename.zip '{}' + && mv filename.zip archive/ \;
```

But those files are not zipped properly. Will anyone please help me in figuring out the mistake my code?

Answer (score 4):

logrotate can do this, the pattern match can be for *log, then you add a section called "postrotate", consider postrotate a small bash script that runs after rotation.

example;

```
/home/usr/logs/*.log {
    daily
    missingok
    compress
    #delaycompress (this will prevent compressing of one day)
    notifempty
    create 640 root adm
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
                mv /home/usr/logs/*.gz /home/usr/logs/archive/;
    endscript
}
```

UPDATE1:

if you want to use zip instead of gzip, add;

```
compresscmd /usr/bin/zip
compressoptions -r
compressext .zip
```

Comment: Thanks mike. But my problem is how to zip each log files with different xtension in name.

Comment: if you mean zip instead of gzip i've added an update, if you mean your src files have a different extension, just change the pattern match from *.log to whatever your files have. for example /home/usr/logs/*.log.gz, it also supports using multiple patterns.